# Azure Function v2 with Jwt Authentication without Certificate

Tags: c#, azure-functions, jwt

I am working on a test Azure Function v2 back end project. The goal is that the function method authorization attributes use the jwt token that I pass from our front end project that use MSAL to authenticate on our v2 app registered on portal azure. My front end project is written in Angular 7 and use this npm package for MSAL https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular. I would use the same registered app for front end and back end project. What can I do in the startup to set jwt authentication and bind it to the function authorization attributes ?

This is a proof of concept project so we would replace our App Service Web API with an Azure Function. The front end and back end project use the same app registered on portal azure. We would still use the same registered app and front end would call the azure function instead of the App Service. I tried to use a binding example from this link https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings , but they use a Certificate. I would like to use the App Id and Tenant Id instead of passing a Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) feature (also known as EasyAuth) actually supports Bearer tokens for authenticating requests for AAD.

To enable the feature for your function app, navigate to your app in the portal. Then go to Platform Features > Networking > Authentication / Authorization. From there, select the advanced configuration for AAD, and provide the client id and Issuer URL for your AAD application registration. Now, your application will be able to authenticate requests that have Bearer tokens with your AAD app registration as the audience.

For the authorization component, you have two choices.

1. Set `Action to take when request is not authenticated` to `Log in with Azure Active Directory`. This is a global setting, so all HTTP requests to your function application are protected by this authorization logic.
2. Set `Action to take when request is not authenticated` to `Allow Anonymous requests (no action)`. In this case, the platform will not perform any authorization logic, and you must implement it your code. While this is more work, it allows you more flexibility about what APIs should be protected, and also allows for more complex authorization logic than just "is the request authenticated?".

   If your HTTP triggers are using C#, you can easily access the [ClaimsPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#working-with-client-identities) object with the AAD identity populated. From there, you can easily perform your authorization logic. JavaScript support should be coming for this feature soon. If you don't have access to this ClaimsPrincipal, you can also manually parse the bearer token and look at the claims present there.

NOTE: Ignore the statement at the top of the documentation about not support MSAL and AAD V2 endpoints. This is no longer the case as of April 2019. The configuration is almost identical for AAD v1 endpoints, but the issuer url has `/v2.0` appended to the end.

Comment: I would like to implement the Authorization in code without using the platform but I don't know how to bind jwt authentication to the native azure function authorization header. The point of using in code authentication/authorization is in using custom policies which is available in mvc projects but I don't know how to achieve this in Functions.